# Anomalous Image Behavior In Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline, pipeline, assets

I'm new to RoR and in my Rails 3.2.3 app without the sprockets gem installed, I've used "image_tag" to display "example.png" which exists in "public/images," like so:

```
<%= image_tag "example.png" %>
```

It works, yet, so far all attempts to display any other image *in the same directory* fail. For example,

```
<%= image_tag "embassy.png" %>
```

...fails, even though the file exists. It's like the app will only display "example.png" and no other image in the same directory. The permissions are the same on all files. The assets pipeline is enabled per,

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

...in "config/application.rb." I've grokked a few resources from the API to random articles and nothing has helped me understand this odd behavior. Can anybody explain either,

1) Why and when Rail behaves like this?

and/or

2) How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `app/assets` directory for storing images, they will be copied into `public/assets` when needed. The images can be loaded from there.

See also the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for more information.

Comment: The same behavior results using app/assets as well, but since posting the question I've noticed the behavior only seems to occur on branches... on master it seems to work fine. So, while I'm at least able to work and get things done, I'm still left scratching my head. Thanks for the response though!